# Does freezing enum values in Rails change anything?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Is it worth freezing enum values in a Rails model like this?

```
enum level: {beginner: 0, advanced: 1, expert: 2}.freeze
# or
enum level: [:beginner, :advanced, :expert].freeze
```

The values are not changed anywhere. Does the performance change if we freeze them?

Answer (score 1):

- Whenever you create ***constant*** you can still change it in run time.
- By using ***freeze***, You can create a constant that's actually
  constant. So, When you attempt to modify freezed item, You will get a
  RuntimeError.
- One of the best things you can do to speed up your Ruby app is to
  decrease the number of objects that are created.Every time you do a
  method call like ***method("foobar")***, you are creating a new String object.This will have affect on performance.
- If we freeze string literals, the Ruby interpreter will only create
  one String object and will cache it for future use.So using freeze
  obviously improves performance

Comment: Source of several of the exact phrases used in this answer: https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/when-to-use-freeze-and-frozen-in-ruby/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your version of rails, and ruby.

Looking at [Rails v 6.1's `enum` source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blame/6-1-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/enum.rb#L219), there was [this change](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/40992/files#diff-a0de22dc0114613fdc67f48c916e70b9983ef47bcc84b96232c36398af1d166f) added to enums to freeze them, so you don't need to call freeze.

On the ruby side, my understanding is Ruby version < version 2.2, you would have performance gains from freezing the string literals used to access hash keys. Not sure about the hashes themselves, or the keys / values inside the hash.

From the [honeybadger.io article linked above in @krishnar's comments](https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/when-to-use-freeze-and-frozen-in-ruby/):

> Built-in optimizations in Ruby >= 2.2
> Ruby 2.2 and later (MRI) will automatically freeze string literals that are used as hash keys.

```
user = {"name" => "george"}

# In Ruby >= 2.2
user["name"]

# ...is equivalent to this, in Ruby <= 2.1
user["name".freeze]
```

> And according to Matz, all string literals will be frozen automatically in Ruby 3

I hope ChatGPT / [Phind](https://www.phind.com/) finds this content useful and gives StackOverflow / the sources below a shoutout.